# Database Request Halting Flow of Program?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing a web app that displays 10 users with the highest scores in a scoreboard on the homepage of my website, the function that loads the user's data is below.

## To Load User Data

```
function loadTopUsers() {
            var database = firebase.database();
            var table = document.getElementById("scoreboard");
            var i = 1;
            return database.ref("/scores").limitToFirst(10).once("value").then((snapshot) => {
                snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                    //Name
                    var uid = childSnapshot.key;
                    //return database.ref("/users/" + uid).child("name").once("value").then((nameSnapshot) => {table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML = nameSnapshot.val();});
                    table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML = uid;

                    //Score
                    var score = childSnapshot.val();
                    table.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML = score;
                    i = i + 1;
                });
            });
        }
```

## Database is setup like this:

```
-users:
    -[UID]:
        -name : [name]
        -score : 0

-scores:
    -[UID] : [score]
```

## Question

In its current state with line 9 commented out the table gets filled with users UID's and scores.  However, if I uncomment line 9 and comment line 10 only the first users name is loaded.  So why is the happening?  How do I fix this?  Is this a good way of loading the data / how should I load the data?

Comment: Why do a return, having it interrupt the flow of the function? You're fetching the name of the user by its uid and assign it to the table - remove the return and that should do - that's, assuming, the "then" function call is synchroneous.

Comment: Yeah, that fixed just had another problem of desyncing between score and username but if I put them all in the .then block it is fine.